# Applying multiple functions on each row using Numba

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba

I have a big 2D NumPy array, let's say 5M rows and 10 columns.  I want to build a few more columns according to some stateful logic implemented using Numba `@jitclass`.  Let's say there are 50 such new columns to create.  The idea is to iterate over all the rows of 10 columns in a Numba `@jit` function, and for each row, apply each of my 50 "filters" to generate one new cell each.  So:

```
 Source1..Source10    Derived1..Derived50
[array of 10 inputs] [array of 50 outputs]
     ... 5 million rows like this ...
```

The problem is, I can't pass a list or tuple of my "filters" to an `@jit(nopython=True)` function, because they are not homogenous:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def calc_derived(source, derived, filters):
    for srcidx, src in enumerate(source):
        for filtidx, filt in enumerate(filters): # doesn't work
            derived[srcidx,filtidx] = filt.transform(src)
```

The above doesn't work because `filters` are a bunch of different classes.  As far as I can tell, even making them derive from a common base class is not good enough.

I am left with the possibility of swapping the order of the loops, and having the loop over the 50 filters outside of the `@jit` function, but this would mean the entire source dataset would be loaded 50 times instead of once, which is very wasteful.

Do you have a technique to work around the "homogenous lists only" requirement of Numba?

Comment: I did have a quick look at this and couldn't quite work out what the problem is. The enumeration over `source` and `filters` should be quick because they're only 10 or 50 elements long. However `src` is 5M elements, and so the real work is done by `filt.transform` (if I understand correctly)? Therefore, I struggled to come up with an illustrative test case where it made any difference how you did the outer loops - provided `filt.transform` is optimised it's all much the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You originally asked about doing this with a single function that loops over rows, and applies a list of filters to each row. A challenge with this approach is that numba needs to know or be able to infer the input/output types of each function. I'm not aware of a way to satisfy numba's requirement in this situation (which is not to say that none exists). If there were a way to do this, it could be a better solution (and I'd like to know what it is).

An alternative is to move the code that loops over rows into the filters themselves. Because the filters are numba functions, this should maintain speed. The function that applies the filters would longer use numba; it would simply loop over the list of filters. But, because the number of filters is small relative to the size of the data matrix, hopefully this won't impact speed too severely. Because this function no longer uses numba, the 'heterogeneous list' issue would no longer be a problem.

This approach worked when I tested it (nopython mode is fine). In test cases, filters implemented as numba functions were 10-18x faster than filters implemented as class methods (even though classes were implemented as numba jitclasses; not sure what's going on there). To gain a bit of modularity, filters can be constructed as closures, so that similar filters can be defined using different parameters.

For example, here are filters that compute sums of powers. Given a matrix `x`, the filter operates over the columns of x, giving an output for each row. It returns a vector `v`, where `v[i] = sum(x[i, :] ** power)`

```
# filter constructor
def sumpow(power):

    @numba.jit(nopython=True)
    def run_filter(x):
        (nrows, ncols) = x.shape
        result = np.zeros(nrows)
        for i in range(nrows):
            for j in range(ncols):
                result[i] += x[i,j] ** power
        return result

    return run_filter

# define filters
sum1 = sumpow(1) # sum of elements
sum2 = sumpow(2) # sum of elements squared

# apply a single filter
v = sum2(x)
```

The function to apply multiple filters looks like this. The output of each filter is stacked into a column of the output.

```
def apply_filters(x, filters):

    result = np.empty((x.shape[0], len(filters)))

    for (i, f) in enumerate(filters):
        result[:, i] = f(x)

    return result


y = apply_filters(x, [sum1, sum2])
```

Timing results

- Data matrix: random entries drawn from standard normal distribution, float64, 5 million rows x 10 columns. All methods tested using the same matrix.
- Filters: `sum2` filter above, repeated 20x in a list: `[sum2, sum2, ...]`
- Timed using IPython's %timeit function, best of 3 runs
- Numerical outputs of all methods agree

> - Numba function filters (as shown above): 2.25s
> - Numba jitclass filters: 28.3s
> - Pure NumPy (using vectorized ops, no loops): 8.64s

I imagine Numba might gain relative to NumPy for more complex filters.

Comment: This is a good and helpful answer.  I was trying to avoid iterating over the data set multiple times, because it is does not fit in cache, so with your solution we end up having to reload from main memory N times, which is unfortunate.  However, it looks like this is still faster than the alternative using Python.

Answer (score 0):

To get a homogeneous list, you could construct a list of the `transform` functions of all filters. In this case, all list elements would would have type `method`.

```
# filters = list of filters
transforms = [x.transform for x in filters]
```

Then pass `transforms` to `calc_derived()` instead of `filters`.

Edit:
On my system, looks like numba will accept this, but only if nopython=False

Comment: As your "Edit" already says, this doesn't work with `nopython=True`.  And if I remove `nopython=True`, the program takes 5x longer to iterate over the rows.  So this doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnZwinck My guess is that the problem is that numba needs to know or be able to infer the input/output types for each function when using nopython mode. If that's true, it would be a constraint on any approach to the problem (or it might give a hint for how to proceed). Hopefully there's a way around it, but I don't know offhand.